# CAML QUERY for getting only tasks of current user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, caml-query, promises

I want to show the user only his tasks on specific list, and show him the option to approve and reject from that view.

In order to get his tasks I have used the below code:

```
        var traineePromise = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
        webURL: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where>\
                 <And>\
                     "+ workflowname + "\
                     <Or>\
                      <Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/><Value Type='Integer'>"+ _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq>\
                      <Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/></Membership>\
                     </Or>\
                 </And>\
             </Where></Query>",
        listName: "Workflow Tasks"
    });

    $.when(traineePromise).done(function () {
     ...
       })
```

Unfortunately, it's not working

Comment: What is the value of `workflowname`? You say it's not working.. What is not working exactly? Are you getting errors?

Comment: You can replace AssignedTo portion with `<FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value>` - This is the equivalent of using the `[Me]` token in views https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can also achieve it by using **REST API**

> /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('workflowname ')/items?$filter=Approver eq ‘username'

Comment: are you sure I can use workflowname inside "getbytitle"?

Comment: yes... look at this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1134731/Approve-Workflow-Tasks-with-SharePoint-REST-API

Comment: 'workflowname' above should be the name of the tasks list. Filtering on the workflow would be done in the `$filter` portion

Comment: To be hones, I don't succeed :(